# call java function from javascript over android webview target version 15

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have use this code:

```
    JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");
```

class

```
JavaScriptInterface:

public class JavaScriptInterface {
    private Activity activity;

    public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activiy) {
        this.activity = activiy;
    }

    public void startVideo(String videoAddress){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoAddress), "video/3gpp"); 
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and js:

```
<a href=''  onclick="window.JSInterface.startVideo('Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Application"+File.separator+test.3gp');" >play

</a>
```

but i am not able to locate the file.

any one have working code for target version below 15.

please post..

thanks in advance.

Comment: "i am not able to locate the file" -- locate *what* file? Does your device actually have an `/sdcard/` directory?

Comment: this is my directory Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Application"+File.separator